# get data from bootstrap modal on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I open a modal if a input element is clicked. The user should choose some data within the modal. On close the chosen data should be displayed in the element that triggered the click-event.

```
<!-- input elements -->
    <div class="wrapper">    
    <div class="row align-items-center mb-2 mt-2 ms-1 "> 
        <input type="text" id="txtMittel[]" name="txtNr1[]" class="form-control openmodal" placeholder="input" >
        <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="txtNr2[]">
        <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="txtNr3[]" value="3">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="add"><img src="../img/add-icon.png" alt="Add"></a>
    </div>      

    <div class="row align-items-center mb-2 mt-2 ms-1 "> 
        <input type="text" id="txtMittel[]" name="txtNr1[]" class="form-control openmodal" placeholder="input" >
        <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="txtNr2[]">
        <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="txtNr3[]" value="3">            
    </div>      

    <div class="row align-items-center mb-2 mt-2 ms-1 "> 
        <input type="text" id="txtMittel[]" name="txtNr1[]" class="form-control openmodal" placeholder="input" >
        <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="txtNr2[]">
        <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="txtNr3[]" value="3">            
    </div>      
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Modal title</h5>
                 <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="divModalBody">
                 <input type="text" id="txtUserInput">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
$("#wrapper").on('click', '.openmodal', function(e){
    $("#modal").modal("show");        
    $("#btnCloseModal").on('click', function() {                     
        e.target.value = $("#txtUserInput").val();
        $(e.target).parent().next().children().val("some other text from the modal");
    });
}); </script>
```

If I am using `e.target.value` it seems to work at first, but if more elements of the class `.example` are clicked, the value of all elements that were clicked before, is also changed

Comment: Generally, don't create event handlers from within other event handlers.

Comment: @Ouroborus any better suggestions? 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new "close" event handler every time you show the dialog but you don't remove these when hiding the dialog. As a result, on close, all old handlers are triggered in addition to the current new handler.

There are two options:

1. Remove the "close" handler when it is triggered:

```js
$("#wrapper").on('click', '.openmodal', function(e){
    $("#modal").modal("show");        
    $("#btnCloseModal").on('click', function() {
        $("#btnCloseModel").off('click');
        e.target.value = $("#txtUserInput").val();
        $(e.target).parent().next().children().val("some other text from the modal");
    });
});
```

2. Declare the close handler once and pass the needed data by outer variable:

```js
let wrapperTarget;
$("#wrapper").on('click', '.openmodal', function(e){
    wrapperTarget = e.target;
    $("#modal").modal("show");
});
$("#btnCloseModal").on('click', function() {
    wrapperTarget.value = $("#txtUserInput").val();
    $(wrapperTarget).parent().next().children().val("some other text from the modal");
});
```

Comment: Option 1 is still the same.... ‍♂️ but option 2 is working  and looks "cleaner" for me